# why can't we set default value of char type variable to ' '

Tags: java, char

Why can't we set default value of char type variable to ' '? Likewise, we can set default value of string variable to " " in Java.

Suppose

```
class abc
{
   private String a="";
   private char b='';//here it will give error
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `''` is not a character literal as defined in the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.4).

```
CharacterLiteral:
    ' SingleCharacter '
    ' EscapeSequence '

SingleCharacter:
    InputCharacter but not ' or \

InputCharacter:
    UnicodeInputCharacter but not CR or LF

UnicodeInputCharacter:
    UnicodeEscape
    RawInputCharacter

UnicodeEscape:
    \ UnicodeMarker HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit

UnicodeMarker:
    u
    UnicodeMarker u

RawInputCharacter:
    any Unicode character

HexDigit: one of
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f A B C D E F
```

On the other hand, [a `String` literal is defined as](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5)

```
StringLiteral:
    " StringCharacters opt "
```

Notice the `opt`, for optional.

Answer (score 0):

A string is basically an array of characters, and an array can be empty without any issues.

Since a character is not an array, it can't be empty, it has to be set to a valid 'character' value.

Comment: you can't set it to `null`

Answer (score 0):

If You want to set char to be empty use:

```
Character c='\u0000'
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score 0):

Try \0.  That would be a good substitute for the empty character primitive.  These is no empty primitive character, it has to be something.